# What is the name of this property of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology

Let $S$ have property $P$ if there exists a function $f(x,y)$ such that:

the domain of $f$ is $(S,S)$
the range of $f$ is $(-1,0,1)$
if $f(a,b) = 1$ and $f(b,c) = 1$ then $f(a,c) = 1$
and if $f(a,b) = 1$ then $f(b,a)$ is $-1$.
and iff $a = b$ then $f(a,b) = 0$.

Questions:
Is there a name for this property and if so what is it?
Does the power set of the reals have this property?

Thanks Noah Schweber for the great answer!

Comment: Your function represents a _total order_ on $S$.

Comment: Note that your notation is nonstandard: we write "$S\times S$" instead of "$(S, S)$", and "$\{-1, 0, 1\}$" instead of "$(-1, 0, 1)$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Arthur said, such a function is a *total order* on the set $S$. (Actually, this isn't quite right: a total order is the binary *relation* induced by such a function - $a\le b\iff f(a)\in\{0, 1\}$, or $a<b\iff f(a)=1$, depending on whether a total order is lax or strict in your context - but there is essentially no difference.)

Now, by the **axiom of choice** (AC), every set has a total order - in fact, a particularly nice one, called a *well-order*. This is the **well-ordering principle** (WO), which is equivalent to AC. The statement "every set has a total order," though, is *weaker* than AC, although still not provable in choiceless set theory (ZF).

As to the specific example of the powerset of the reals: it is indeed consistent with ZF that there is no linear order on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. This is of course very difficult to prove (since such consistency proofs require **forcing**, a very technical proof method in set theory), but the key point is that it is consistent with ZF that there is a set of sets of reals which is **amorphous** (that is, infinite but not partitionable into two disjoint infinite subsets), and no set with an amorphous subset can have a total order. This is a nice exercise (although perhaps hard):

> Any totally ordered set is not amorphous.

*HINT: Let $S$ be totally ordered, and suppose $S$ were amorphous. Then for each $s\in S$, letting $L(s)=\{x: x<s\}$, $R(s)=\{x: x>s\}$, we have that exactly one of $L(s)$ and $R(s)$ is infinite. Let $X=\{s: L(s)$ is infinite$\}$, $Y=\{s: R(s)$ is infinite$\}$. Do you see why both $X$ and $Y$ must be infinite, and why they are disjoint?*

---

EDIT: You ask for a sketch of why every set can be linearly ordered. This is a great question! The proof is surprisingly complicated in full detail: it requires the axiom of choice, and even then the way the axiom is *used* is a bit subtle.

What I'm going to do is just give the outline of the argument; there's a lot to fill in, but hopefully this will give you some intuition for why the statement is true (assuming Choice), and also maybe for what the axiom of choice is doing!

Let's say I have a set $S$ I want to give a total order. Now, maybe I can't order the whole set $S$ (I mean, I can, but I don't know how to *yet*), but I can certainly give total orders to *subsets* of $S$. For example, it's easy to totally order a one-element set :P.

So let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of all *totally ordered subsets of $S$* - that is, an element of $\mathbb{P}$ is a pair $(A, f)$ (I'm using your terminology here) where

- $A$ is a subset of $S$, and
- $f$ is a function with domain $A\times A$ which gives a total order on $A$.

Now on the face of it, $\mathbb{P}$ is just a set - but it turns out there's a bit more going on here! $\mathbb{P}$ is in fact a **partial order**: given $(A, f)$ and $(B, g)$ in $\mathbb{P}$, say $(A, f)$ **extends** $(B, g)$ if

- $A$ contains $B$, and
- $f$ agrees with $g$ on $B$: $g(b_1, b_2)=f(b_1, b_2)$ for all $b_1, b_2\in B$.

This is a bit weird, so let me give an example: maybe $A=\{x, y, z\}$ and $B=\{x, y\}$, and $f$ says $x<y<z$ and $g$ says $x<y$. Then $(A, f)$ extends $(B, g)$. The point is, $(A, f)$ provides even more of a total order than $(B, g)$ does, and it doesn't "change" any facts about the part $g$ has already ordered.

OK, so far so good? This is a really weird thing to do out of the blue, so take some time to think about what $\mathbb{P}$ is . . .

Now here's what we do with it:

- Suppose $S$ *cannot* be totally ordered, for contradiction.
- Then for any $(A, f)\in\mathbb{P}$, there is some $a\in S$ with $a\not\in A$.
- But we can always "add $a$ to $(A, f)$": we can totally order $A\cup\{a\}$ by putting $a$ above every element of $A$. So this gives us a new condition $(B, g)$ extending $(A, f)$ with $a\in B$.
- Now the idea is to "keep doing this" and show that we can in fact totally order the whole of $S$. However, this is where things get complicated: we might need to iterate this process *infinitely many times*! So to make this formal, we need some technical machinery, and this is where the axiom of choice comes in. In particular, for a given $(A, f)$, there will be *lots* of $a$s not in $A$; and we need to pick one to move forward with the construction. The axiom of choice, very broadly speaking, lets us perform "infinitely long" constructions like this even when there is no obvious guiding pattern.

Comment: could you give a proof or at least some intuition as to why all sets have a total order.

Comment: @mathew Are you familiar with the axiom of choice, or with Zorn's lemma? (I need to know where to start the intuition from.)

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with either, my knowledge is very limited

Comment: @mathew Alright, I'm writing an intuitive sketch - it will take me a few minutes. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I think I understand, your adding a new element from S to this ordered set A over and over again until you have used up all of S. This makes me uncomfortable though because without any particular pattern to how your adding these new members, doing it infinity many times would seem to create problems. For example, you might argue that the reals and integers have the same cardinality because you could keep adding reals to a set until you have all of them and do this in some ordered way so as to match each with an integer. (I am familiar with cantors diagonal proof so I know this is invalid)

Comment: How is this different then? what allows you to simply say, "keep adding to the ordered  set". S could have an uncountably infinite number of members left to order so you can't really just add one after another and be able to get to all of them

Comment: @mathew Yes, and this is exactly the sort of technical detail I'm hiding here. This is where the axiom of choice (and in fact a bit of transfinite induction) comes into play. Like I said, what I wrote above is **not** a proof: it's a very rough picture of what's going on. Look up a proof of the well-ordering theorem from the axiom of choice if you want to see all the rigorous details (you should!).

Comment: Thanks, this has been really interesting! If you don't mind I have one more question about the axiom of choice. I just looked it up on wikipedia and it seems to be really obvious. If I understand correctly all it is saying is that if you have a set of non empty sets there exists a function that gives some element of each set. This seems so obvious I'm not sure how it could be useful

Comment: I'll point out one thing though: if you try to build a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ this way, what goes wrong is that you may (in fact, always will) have a partial bijection which misses some reals, but has already used up all the naturals; that is, the construction isn't done yet, but you can't proceed any further. The point is that there is no such possible obstruction in this case (although of course that takes proof), and in the absence of an obstruction the axiom of choice lets the argument go through.

Comment: @mathew The axiom of choice is surprisingly powerful! Horrst Herrlich has a book ("The axiom of choice") that I quite like on this. Look up the Banach-Tarski paradox for an unusual consequence of AC; and on the positive side, note that set theory without choice can't even prove that every infinite set can be partitioned into two infinite pieces! (See my comments about amorphous sets, above.)

Comment: why can't partitioning of an infinite set be done without the axiom choice? for example the integers are an infinite set. you can create two infinite sets, the odds and evens or negatives and positives.

Comment: @mathew Some infinite sets can indeed be so partitioned; however, without the axiom of choice, there might be others which can't. The proof of this is extremely hard - really one of the jewels of set theory - but you can find it in advanced set theory texts like Kunen or Jech.